# Running a script from CIFS mount point location

Tags: linux, shell-script, cifs

I have a shell script located in Windows file share. The file share is mounted on a Linux VM via CIFS mount point. Now, if I execute the shell script from the Linux VM, where will this script actually run and get executed? Will the script run in Linux VM although the it is present in the Windows file share?

Thanking in advance :)

Comment: Depends entirely on the script and your current working directory, if by "run" you mean the working directory where it executes.

Answer (score 3):

The shell in a linux VM will read the script and execute the commands within the VM; the Windows OS is just allowing the VM to access files on the share. The ability for the VM to request Windows to run processes on the Windows system would require a separate service with its own authentication, e.g. [PowerShell SSH remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-7.3).